# Apache SSL works but the config shows it's only listening on 80 not 443, how is it possible?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, openvpn, centos6

Server: CentOS 6, Apache 2.2 and OpenVPN installed.

The httpd.conf has:

```
#Listen 443
Listen 80
```

Websites work in https so I think OpenVPN might be listening on 443 and forwarding to Apache (port-share), but I can't find this config.
Also, if this were the case, Apache should be listening on a second port to accept the forwarded requests, shouldn't it?

I have searched all config includes and there are no other Listen directives. I've also restarted Apache.

If I try to see what process listens on 443:

```
# lsof -i tcp:443

COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd   1635   root    6u  IPv6 352710      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
httpd   1259 apache    6u  IPv6 352710      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
httpd   2286 apache    6u  IPv6 352710      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
```

The last two lines are repeated about 20 times but with different PIDs.

Also tried:

```
# netstat -tulpn

tcp     0    0 :::443     :::*    LISTEN  1635/httpd
```

The above all seem to show that Apache is the one listening. I have verified that I'm working with the correct httpd.conf.

If I uncomment the #Listen 443 and restart Apache, I get an error that the port is already in use.

Also, I have tried commenting out one of the SSL vhosts to see if the site went down, and it did, so I know this is the correct Apache (rules out a separate Apache install I think).

The only thing I can find in OpenVPN's as.conf is this:

```
# web server will use three consecutive ports starting at this
# address, for use with the OpenVPN port share feature
cs.dynamic_port_base=870
```

How can I find out what's listening on 443 so I can stop it and have Apache listen normally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SSL configuration, including the `Listen` directive for port 443, is in the `/etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_ssl.conf` file. If you don't find that file, or don't find the proper `Listen` directive in that file, then something is beyond wacky with your system.

Comment: Thank you, the Listen was indeed in conf.d, I had only searched the conf. In my `lsof` output, is it normal to have `root` there? Apache should be running as the `apache` user.

Comment: Apache has to start as root to bind to privileged (<1024) ports. It then drops privs to `apache` and runs as that user, so while I've never looked as `lsof` in this instance, I'm not entirely surprised to see `root` there.